# Ubuntu Server RAID6 (md) + LVM2: formatting stuck at 33%

Tags: server, raid, lvm, mdadm, xfs

**BIG NOTE**. I am not a newbie with Linux and this is not the first time I install Linux in such a manner.

I am installing a new Ubuntu Server (16.04, x86_64). Its four disks have been put together to create a RAID6 device (md0).

This has then been partitioned in two: a main physical partition (md0p1) for the host system (mounted as /), a secondary logical partition (md0p5) has been used to create a logical volume for users (/home). This choice will allow me to add more "room" to users, while the system partition won't need any "enlargement". I have 64GB RAM so the absence of a swap partition in the installation process isn't a problem.

The installation process seems to be stuck at 33% of the LV.
From another virtual console I can see the formatting process is still running with status being "D" (Disk sleep).
The log is being output to /var/log/partman and its last few lines are:

```
parted_server: OUT 1:    0-<bignumber>455 <bignumber>456 primary xfs /dev/mapper/VGHOST-HOSTHOME

parted_server: Closing infifo outfifo
parted_server: main loop: iteration 925
parted_server: Opening infifo
```

There is no update here as well.
I think this is a bug for this specific case as there's no hardware error in the syslog and dmesg logs and because I already did same type of installation in the past with no hassles.

Any idea on how to un-stuck my installation?

P.S.
I can boot a GUI based Ubuntu medium, but only if there's no option, i.e. this is a bug in the installer.